# Visual Studio doesn't see my new .CS files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Plugin.cs
--Sync (folder)
  |  CreateDateCrawler.cs
  |  ModDateCrawler.cs
--Helpers (folder) 
  |  MyHelper.cs
```

All of these files are in the same namespace.
Plugin.cs can't see any of the other .cs files. Intelli-sense doesn't pick any of them up, and I get an error (see below) if I add them manually.

[image: Visual Studio ERROR!]

However, and this is where it gets weird, CreateDateCrawler.cs can see/use MyHelper.cs.

This seems crazy to me, because Plugin.cs is in the root directory, but MyHelper is a directory down, and then up. If MyHelper.cs can see them, why not Plugin.cs?

I have a feeling this is an IDE thing, but I don't know enough about Visual Studio to know how to fix it.

Another thing: I just added both of these files. I grabbed them from another folder, right-click->copy, pasted, then renamed. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Question: Why can only some of my files see these classes? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand you. Files don't see each other. Whether you write your whole code in one gigantic source file or you organize the source code for your different classes in different files doesn't matter at all, as long as all the source code files are together in the same project. (It also doesn't matter whether the files are in different folders, as long as they are all in the same Visual Studio project)

Comment: Are you sure they are all in the same namespace? The default behaviour of Visual Studio is to put files in the project root in the PROJECTNAME namespace, and then if a file is in a subfolder, it will be in the PROJECTNAME.SUBFOLDER namespace, etc. You can change this manually of course, but that's the default of how VS works. Now are you sure they are all in the PROJECTNAME namespace and not in a different namespace (e.g. PROJECTNAME.SUBFOLDER)?

Comment: what errors, please show code and the error messages

Comment: To add to what @elgonzo said, a single file can contain many type declarations (e.g. classes, interfaces, etc.). There isn't a one-to-one file/class relationship, and a class in a file doesn't have to have the same name as the filename.

Comment: "_gives an error_" What is the error? What does it spell out? Read the error, try to understand it...

Comment: Why don't you read the error message text? The error message is shown in two places in Visual Studio: first and foremost in the error list panel, and secondly it will show in a tooltip if you hover with the mouse over the red wiggly line. It shouldn't be an unsurmountable task ...

Comment: @PeterAndrus Please [edit] your question with the declarations of Plugin.cs and MyHelper.cs (the imports, the `namespace` line and the `public class x` line)

Comment: I edited it for clarity, but i'll add some pictures as well. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the classes which see each other are the ones you c&p'ed.
Most likely the are in another namespace, than your Plugin.
So just add

```
using TheNameSpaceYourHelperIsIn;
```

to the Plugin.cs, where those other usings are. Or you could also put them all in the same namespace.

Just try CTRL + . on the class, that is not known, there should be something like this:
[image]

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you. I was actually editing it when i realized i wasn't actually "using" the same namespace that all of these are in. Strangely enough, only the "Plugin" class needed the "using" to be added. The rest don't have it, but they see that class? They all have the same: "namespace XXX.XXX" declaration at the top? This is my deficiency in C# (I just started using it at work) showing through i suppose. 
Anyways, it can see that class now, so thanks.

Comment: if they are already in the same namespace, they "see" each other.